# Search Flickr Using Retrofit and GSON

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, flickr

I am looking to use Retrofit and the Flickr API to allow users to search and use images in my application. Being new to Retrofit and REST requests in general, I was hoping for some help.

I am making a basic application that has an EditText and a button. When the button is pressed, I want to search Flickr based on that term.

I have the basic code to get started and was hoping somebody could help me finish it up:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mSearchTerm;
private Button mRequestButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSearchTerm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ediText_search_term);
    mRequestButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.request_button);
    mRequestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String typedText = mSearchTerm.getText().toString();
        }
    });


    RestAdapter restAdapter=new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=MYKEY&user_id=MYID&format=json")
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)//log your request
            .build();
}

public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("UNSURE")  //
    void getPhotos(@Query("q") String city, Callback<UNSURE> callback);
     }

  }
```